# Do problems that have unary encodings automatically become unary languages?

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity, runtime-analysis

This problem has confused me a lot, can any of you help me out. 
Thank you.

Comment: (1) Every problem has a unary encoding. (2) A unary language is a subset of $\sigma^*$ for some letter $\sigma$. No more no less.

Answer (score 1):

A unary language is a subset of $\sigma^*$ for some letter $\sigma$. If your language is of this form, then it is unary. Otherwise it isn't.

A unary *encoding* is an encoding of some data as a subset of $\sigma^*$. For example, one possible unary encoding of the natural numbers is $n \mapsto 1^n$. Any language in which instances are unary encoded is a unary language, simply because it is a subset of $\sigma^*$. For example, the language of all primes encoded in unary is a unary language.

Comment: Thank you for your time sir

Comment: Can you also provide me a reference for your answer.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean by reference.